# How to best optimize calculations iterated over NxM grid in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, iteration

Working in Python, I am doing some physics calculations over an NxM grid of values, where N goes from 1 to 3108 and M goes from 1 to 2304 (this corresponds to a large image). I need calculate a value at each and every point in this space, which totals ~ 7 million calculations. My current approach is painfully slow, and I am wondering if there is a way to complete this task and it not take hours...

My first approach was just to use nested for loops, but this seemed like the least efficient way to solve my problem. I have tried using NumPy's nditer and iterating over each axis individually, but I've read that it doesn't actually speed up my computations. Rather than looping through each axis individually, I also tried making a 3-D array and looping through the outer axis as shown in Brian's answer here [How can I, in python, iterate over multiple 2d lists at once, cleanly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189087/how-can-i-in-python-iterate-over-multiple-2d-lists-at-once-cleanly) .  Here is the current state of my code:

```py
import numpy as np
x,y = np.linspace(1,3108,num=3108),np.linspace(1,2304,num=2304) # x&y dimensions of image
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
all_coords = np.dstack((X,Y)) # moves to 3-D
all_coords = all_coords.astype(int) # sets coords to int
```

For reference, all_coords looks like this:

```py
array([[[1.000e+00, 1.000e+00],
        [1.000e+00, 2.000e+00],
        [1.000e+00, 3.000e+00],
        ...,
        [1.000e+00, 2.302e+03],
        [1.000e+00, 2.303e+03],
        [1.000e+00, 2.304e+03]],

       [[2.000e+00, 1.000e+00],
        [2.000e+00, 2.000e+00],
        [2.000e+00, 3.000e+00],
        ...,
        [2.000e+00, 2.302e+03],
        [2.000e+00, 2.303e+03],
        [2.000e+00, 2.304e+03]],
```

and so on. Back to my code...

```py
'''
- below is a function that does a calculation on the full grid using the distance between x0,y0 and each point on the grid.
- the function takes x0,y0 and returns the calculated values across the grid
'''
def do_calc(x0,y0):
    del_x, del_y = X-x0, Y-y0
    np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
    dmx_ij = (del_x/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # x component
    dmy_ij = (del_y/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # y component
    return dmx_ij,dmy_ij

# now the actual loop

def do_loop():
    dmx,dmy = 0,0
    for pair in all_coords:
        for xi,yi in pair:
            DM = do_calc(xi,yi)
            dmx,dmy = dmx+DM[0],dmy+DM[1]
    return dmx,dmy
```

As you might see, this code takes an incredibly long time to run... If there is any way to modify my code such that it doesn't take hours to complete, I would be extremely interested in knowing how to do that. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is the code you gave your actual computation? Probably not since it will return only a bunch of `NaN`s. The code as it stands (after fixing the `NaN` issue) is easily accelerated (using translation invariance), but this might not generalize to a more realistic per point function. It is therefore essential for you to give more information. For example, does everything only depend on coordinates? Or do the pixel values also enter the calculation? Is the real computation or at least parts of it translation invariant?

Comment: The only place the above computation would result in a NaN is at the location (x0,y0). Across the rest of the grid there are real values. The NaN location is something I do handle appropriately in my actual code. The full calculation I use in my code is almost exactly as it is described above, except with another  term in front indexed by (x0,y0) that I did not bother mentioning or describing for simplicity. You can consider the code above (aside from the NaN issue that I handle appropriately) as complete and the code that I am trying to optimize. Thanks.

Comment: Funny, when I run your code I get nothing but `NaN`s. Hint: Every point of your grid is `x0, y0` once in the iteration and a single `NaN` term suffices to make an entire sum `NaN`. Anyway, I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Awesome, I am interested in what your solution is. Yes you are correct about the NaNs. If you catch it when the division by zero happens and set it some other value then everything works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that gives a 10,000x speedup at `N=310, M=230`. As the method scales better than the original code I'd expect a factor of more than a million at the full problem size.

The method exploits the shift invariance of the problem. For example, `del_x**2` is essentially the same up to shift at each call of `do_calc`, so we compute it only once.

If the output of `do_calc` is weighted before summation the problem is no longer fully translation invariant, and this method doesn't work anymore. The result, however, can then be expressed in terms of linear convolution. At `N=310, M=230` this still leaves us with a more than 1,000x speedup. And, again, this will be more at full problem size

Code for original problem

```
import numpy as np

#N, M = 3108, 2304
N, M = 310, 230

### OP's code

x,y = np.linspace(1,N,num=N),np.linspace(1,M,num=M) # x&y dimensions of image
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
all_coords = np.dstack((X,Y)) # moves to 3-D
all_coords = all_coords.astype(int) # sets coords to int

'''
- below is a function that does a calculation on the full grid using the distance between x0,y0 and each point on the grid.
- the function takes x0,y0 and returns the calculated values across the grid
'''
def do_calc(x0,y0):
    del_x, del_y = X-x0, Y-y0
    np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
    dmx_ij = (del_x/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # x component
    dmy_ij = (del_y/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # y component
    return np.nan_to_num(dmx_ij), np.nan_to_num(dmy_ij)

# now the actual loop

def do_loop():
    dmx,dmy = 0,0
    for pair in all_coords:
        for xi,yi in pair:
            DM = do_calc(xi,yi)
            dmx,dmy = dmx+DM[0],dmy+DM[1]
    return dmx,dmy

from time import time

t = [time()]

### pp's code

x, y = np.ogrid[-N+1:N-1:2j*N - 1j, -M+1:M-1:2j*M - 1J]
den = x*x + y*y
den[N-1, M-1] = 1
xx = x / den
yy = y / den
for zz in xx, yy:
    zz[N:] -= zz[:N-1]
    zz[:, M:] -= zz[:, :M-1]
XX = xx.cumsum(0)[N-1:].cumsum(1)[:, M-1:]
YY = yy.cumsum(0)[N-1:].cumsum(1)[:, M-1:]
t.append(time())

### call OP's code for reference

X_OP, Y_OP = do_loop()
t.append(time())

# make sure results are equal

assert np.allclose(XX, X_OP)
assert np.allclose(YY, Y_OP)
print('pp {}\nOP {}'.format(*np.diff(t)))
```

Sample run:

```
pp 0.015251636505126953
OP 149.1642508506775
```

Code for weighted problem:

```
import numpy as np

#N, M = 3108, 2304
N, M = 310, 230

values = np.random.random((N, M))
x,y = np.linspace(1,N,num=N),np.linspace(1,M,num=M) # x&y dimensions of image
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
all_coords = np.dstack((X,Y)) # moves to 3-D
all_coords = all_coords.astype(int) # sets coords to int

'''
- below is a function that does a calculation on the full grid using the distance between x0,y0 and each point on the grid.
- the function takes x0,y0 and returns the calculated values across the grid
'''
def do_calc(x0,y0, v):
    del_x, del_y = X-x0, Y-y0
    np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
    dmx_ij = (del_x/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # x component
    dmy_ij = (del_y/((del_x**2)+(del_y**2))) # y component
    return v*np.nan_to_num(dmx_ij), v*np.nan_to_num(dmy_ij)

# now the actual loop

def do_loop():
    dmx,dmy = 0,0
    for pair, vv in zip(all_coords, values):
        for (xi,yi), v in zip(pair, vv):
            DM = do_calc(xi,yi, v)
            dmx,dmy = dmx+DM[0],dmy+DM[1]
    return dmx,dmy

from time import time
from scipy import signal

t = [time()]
x, y = np.ogrid[-N+1:N-1:2j*N - 1j, -M+1:M-1:2j*M - 1J]
den = x*x + y*y
den[N-1, M-1] = 1
xx = x / den
yy = y / den
XX, YY = (signal.fftconvolve(zz, values, 'valid') for zz in (xx, yy))

t.append(time())
X_OP, Y_OP = do_loop()
t.append(time())
assert np.allclose(XX, X_OP)
assert np.allclose(YY, Y_OP)
print('pp {}\nOP {}'.format(*np.diff(t)))
```

Sample run:

```
pp 0.12683939933776855
OP 158.35225439071655
```

Comment: Amazing.. I’ll be testing this in my full code soon. Before summing, it would be trivial to multiply the calculated field by a value indexed by (x0,y0), correct? In reality I have another grid with masses at each point, so before summing I need to scale each calculated field from do_calc(x0,y0) by the mass at point (x0,y0). I suppose i should have included that in the original post for clarity.

Comment: @astro_lukas It's not fully trivial but straight-forward. The second version addresses this, `values` is a random array that would correspond to your masses.